# I can't select something and what is an active object?

Tags: modeling, selection-tools

[image: the part I cant select]

I can't seem to select hull 003. ( the thicker part at the beginning of the corridor is hull003 )

Could this be related to what the active object is?
I can't find what the active object means, nor if this is important or not.
I see tutorials on how to switch but nobody explains why you would wanna do this.

Of course I googled this problem, and somebody was asked if he had used an modifyer.
As you can see I used solidify.

It's driving me nuts, right clicking in the scene properties to select hull 003 does not seem to work either.

Comment: you are in Edit mode, are you sure you don't want to be in Object mode instead? The active object is the last selected, it has several uses, like for example when you want to parent, or copy a material or a modifier from another object, etc...

Comment: @moonboots
Thank you. Will try to remember that active object only means its the last one you selected.

I would like to try to use bevel, on the hull 003, and probably want to poke some holes in it, to make it look more truss like.

Comment: We Have a winner :P 

Solution in object mode. Make it local. 
Now when switching to edit mode I can ones again select it. :)
I also flipped the normals.

Comment: Slowly but steady, one day I will understand blender.

https://i.imgur.com/51ZoMmT.png

Comment: I'm not sure anyone is able to know 100% of Blender, it's like a labyrinth ah ah

Comment: Baby steps forward:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fbJrFz2nKls

Comment: ah ah ok, was it to make a background screen?

Comment: My original idea was to make a fly through through a sci fi corridor.
With some parts reacting to the music.

I am close but I am starting to worry about the total render time it will take.
I might have to start a new topic for that.?
The music track is around 4-5 minutes. What I am trying to make is a video to go with the track.

To make the coridor longer could be easy with an array.
That how ducky 3D makes endless loop videos.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X2lw9JwTrI8&list=PLNShHVjao84f33iutaehtc_k6pR_hZMKt&index=2

Comment: yes I saw this kind of videos, the total render time will depend on a lot of things: amount of objects, materials, lights, sampling, resolution... If you open a new question make sure it's not to broad...